why synchronization multibit heavy
I have a Multivit wallet that had some Bitcoin in it, but the synchronization is very heavy. What should I do to be able to send it?

Multibit and Multibit HD became obsolete around seven years ago, because the new owners felt there were too many bugs to fix. Therefore Multibit should not be used if you care about security. It is certainly possible that obsolete, old, unmaintained software would not be able to synchronise today.
I would instead read answers to How to import multibit private key to bitcoin core? and similar questions here
There do seem to be new websites using the name Multibit. I assume they are run by scammers trying to steal money from people who don't check financial businesses thoroughly.
